dspace 8 backend upgrade - The HAL Browser files missing
While upgrading from Dspace 7.5 to 8. I have used following instructions
If you are upgrading from DSpace 7.x, you will need to perform the following steps.
https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC8x/Upgrading+DSpace

As of DSpace 8, the "db.dialect" configuration has changed from
"org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect" to
"org.dspace.util.DSpacePostgreSQLDialect".  Therefore, MAKE SURE that
your dspace.cfg or local.cfg has this setting: db.dialect =
org.dspace.util.DSpacePostgreSQLDialect
Make sure your existing local.cfg is in the source directory (e.g.
[dspace-source]/dspace/config/local.cfg).  That way your existing
configuration gets reinstalled alongside the new version of DSpace.

I clone the repo from https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace.git and copy the older version 7.5 local.cfg file change the db dialect as above.
I have upgraded the
Java 17 (Oracle or OpenJDK)
Apache Maven 3.8.x or above
Tomcat 

On 7.5 version (http://localhost:8080/server/) I get The Hal Browser working fine.

After upgrading to 8.0 version, I get this

When I further investigate, and noticed directory structure in tomcat webapps folder (/opt/tomcat/webapps/server) is different in version 8 as compare to version 7.5.
version 7.5

version 8

When I run the build using
mvn -U clean package 

it gave me success
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:32 min

and when I run
cd [dspace-source]/dspace/target/dspace-installer
ant update


build_webapps_wars:
[echo]
[echo] ====================================================================
[echo]  Updated DSpace Web application directories are in the
[echo]  '/opt/dspace/webapps' directory.
[echo]
[echo]  * Stop your Web servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, Resin etc.)
[echo]
[echo]  * If your Web servlet container already loads the DSpace
[echo]    UI web applications from /opt/dspace/webapps/, then you
[echo]    can jump straight to restarting your Web servlet container
[echo]
[echo]  * Otherwise, you will need to copy any web applications from
[echo]    /opt/dspace/webapps/ to the appropriate place for your servlet
[echo]    container.  (e.g. '$CATALINA_HOME/webapps' for Tomcat)
[echo]
[echo]    If you're using Tomcat, you should first delete any existing
[echo]    DSpace directories in '$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/' (e.g. you would
[echo]    delete an existing $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/dspace/ directory).
[echo]    Otherwise, Tomcat may continue to use old code in that directory.
[echo]
[echo]  * Start up your Web servlet container again.
[echo] ====================================================================
[echo]
update:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 13 seconds


I even looked into /dspace/target/dspace-installer/webapps/server folder just to confirm that is not copying issue. but directory structure is same as tomcat webapp as above (different for version 8 and 7)
I also created the index.html file in to make sure tomcat is mapping the directory correctly, on visiting http://localhost:8080  index.html is opening OK. which means tomcat is working OK.
I am learning java and Dspace, any help would be appreciated. What am I missing.

When you run git status --ignored in the directory with the dspace source, what does it shows you?
